# Documentation on GeoGridPosition

Tags: geodesy

Wondering where I can find more documentation on `GeoGridPosition`. Specifically, what formulas does *Mathematica* use to transform lat/long points to x/y coordinates? As a test point, I do the following:

```
    GeoGridPosition[GeoPosition[{45, -45}], "Mercator"]
```

which returns:

```
    GeoGridPosition[{-45, (180 Log[Cot[π/8]])/π}, "Mercator"]
```

which can be simplified to the point {-45, 50.499}, I just don't know how this is computed, or what *Mathematica* uses as a reference. If anyone could explain or point me in the right direction, that'd be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure whether your question concerns what mathematical transformations are used or what the geodetic reference parameters are for a particular projection. Perhaps you are concerned about both issues.

- To learn about the geodetic reference parameters are for a particular projection, refer to [`GeoProjectionData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GeoProjectionData.html).
- To learn about the mathematics of a particular projection, Google on the projections name. To learn what projections are available, again refer to `GeoProjectionData`.

However, one can make a good guess about the mathematical transform directly from the result given by `GeoGridPosition` by posing a request that uses distinctive primes as latitude and longitude values.

For example:

```
GeoGridPosition[GeoPosition[{17, 43}], "Mercator"]
```

> ```
> GeoGridPosition[{43, (180 Log[Cot[(73 π)/360]])/π}, "Mercator"]
> ```

Noting that 73 is the colatitude of 17, this suggests that the transform is

```
toMercator[lat_, long_] := {long, 180 Log[Cot[(90 - lat) π/360]]/π}
```

Some tests to confirm this finding.

```
toMercator[17, 43]
```

> ```
> {43, (180 Log[Cot[(73 π)/360]])/π}
> ```

```
toMercator[45, -45]
```

> ```
> {-45, (180 Log[Cot[π/8]])/π}
> ```

This works for other projections as well. Here is a more complex but still informative example.

```
 GeoGridPosition[GeoPosition[{17, 43}], "Albers"]
```

> ```
> GeoGridPosition[
>   {4 Sqrt[1/3 (1-1/2 Sqrt[3] Sin[(17 π)/180])] Sin[(43 π)/(240 Sqrt[3])], 
>    4/Sqrt[3]-4 Cos[(43 π)/(240 Sqrt[3])] Sqrt[1/3 (1-1/2 Sqrt[3] Sin[(17 π)/180])]}, 
>   "Albers"]
> ```

I won't work out a *Mathematica* projection function from this, but I think you can see the form it would take fairly well.